# How to add struct parameters into List

Tags: c#-4.0

I am having interface in that I have a List

```
     public interface IDisplayListQueue 
     {
     void BindQueueData();
    List<HomePage.QueueListItem> QueueDataSource { get; set; }
    }
```

In HomePage.cs, I am having the struct

```
       public struct QueueListItem
        {
        public int QueueID { get; set; }
        public int LinkText { get; set; }
        public int Uid { get; set; }

      }
```

In the page Load i am taking one switch to add the list values.So I am trying to binding the QueueListItem  ,but it shows the error.My code is

```
          switch (queue.QueueTypeID)
           {
           case (int)QueryType.DataEntry:
            dataEntry.QueueDataSource.Add(queue.QueueID, queueName, sentinel );
            break;
           case (int)QueryType.Sort:
             Sort.QueueDataSource.Add(queue.QueueID, queueName, sentinel );
            break;
           }
```

The error I am getting is no overload 'Add' takes 3 arguments. So how to add values to the QueueListItem  which is in interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to create instance of the `struct` and add it to the list, you can do it like:

```
dataEntry.QueueDataSource.Add(new QueueListItem()
                                { 
                                 QueueID= queue.QueueID, 
                                 LinkText= queueName, 
                                 Uid = sentinel
                                 });
```

The `Add` method of your List expect an object of struct `QueueListItem` and you are passing three parameters. You should see: [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx)

Comment: It is working fine,Thanks.One more question ,After adding the details,if we want to find out the value in QueueID ,how should we find?

Comment: @lakki, you are welcome, To find the value you have to first get the item from the list and then select its `QueueID` for example `dataEntry.QueueDataSource.FirstOrDefault().QueueID`

Comment: I am getting null reference exception in{QueueID= queue.QueueID,LinkText= queueName, Uid = sentinel }.Any idea?

Comment: @lakki, probably your `queue` is null, that is why the exception, make sure you have instantiated your queue before using its instance members

Comment: all there parameters getting the null reference exception.QueueListItem i need to initiate?

Comment: @lakki, yes you have to, I thought you already did that, instantiate `dataEntry.QueueDataSource` and `Sort.QueueDataSource` before using them